# Hide a lighting component in the Experience builder

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-web-components, permissions, experience-builder-page

I'm trying to hide a lighting component in the Experience builder. I use "audience" to define which component is visible to which community user - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_edit_pages.htm&type=5

I though it makes sense to do it based on a `permission set`. But there is a way to hide whatever I want to hide for a `Profile`, `Location`, `Role` and a bunch of other things, but not for a permission set. If you look at the picture below the `criteria type` field does have some permission options, but those are not permission sets.

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are custom permissions. Custom permissions let you define access checks that can be assigned to users via permission sets or profiles, similar to how you assign user permissions and other access settings.

Custom permissions can be used in the "Audience", to control the visibility. Following is the link to the documentation for the creation and usage.

Documentation : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/custom_perms_overview.htm

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.